# Spring3 @PostConstruct goes null after tomcat starts and get a Null Object when trying to use on a Service Class

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-mvc, null, postconstruct

hello everyone what Im trying to do is prefill a CustomDetail Object with some properties with  the help of @Value   and @PostConstruct, then use this prefilled Object on a service
but when the Object arrives to the service class its null already...

UPDATED!!!! this is the right code

```
@Service
public Class CustomDetail(){


 ProxyObject prx; 
 ...
 @Value("#{myProperties.proxy.address}")
 String propertyPrx;

 @PostConstruct
 private void setProperty(){
  prx= new ProxyObject(propertyPrx);
 }
 .....
 ....
}
```

Now setProperty() method effectively does its job correctly, if I Start Tomcat on debug I can see that propertyPrx its good and the Object prx is NOT null... so new ProxyObject(propertyPrx) gets Called without any issues, at this point everything fine.
now when I move to the service part 
and try to useit

```
public Class ServiceClient(){

 ....
 ...
 @Autowired
 CustomDetail cDetail;


 ....
 ...more code
  cDetail.someMethod(a,n,y);   //<---cDetail Object is null so I get a NullPointerException

}
```

any ideas why this is happening and why the @PostConstruct only gets initialized when Tomcat starts for the first time  and when I try to injected into the service class is already null like if it never got initialized  thanks for your help...
 I'm using SpringMVC 3.1 Tomcat

Comment: Can you please also show the place where you have the bean definition of ServiceClient, is it also annotated with @Service?

Comment: no it does not have any @annotation(Component,Service... at least not in the original one nor any bean definition on any .xml file) I have tried with all this before and nothing appears to replicate the original code so I'm thinking maybe its some configuration(apart from Subin suggestion have tried also the <context approaches in my appContext.xml they reside in there both of them) issue or the code is pointing somewhere else I wish I know  what is wrong. kind of feeling like a dead end here... Thanks

Comment: I think that is the problem Jesse, Autowired works by scanning bean definitions, looking for @Autowired annotated fields and injecting in the dependencies, so even ServiceClient has to be a Spring bean for it's dependencies to be wired in by Spring.

Comment: I have found a xml file containing the bean reference to ServiceClient  in the original code, still no luck on getting this to work on my new code.Im trying to use @Component("serviceClient") so there will be a bean reference with the same name, I'm not sure if doing both xml style beans and annotations cause some incompatibility between them? still the "@"autowired CustomDetail object goes null at that point. What I did test was to Autowired CustomDetail on a "@"Controller and it works so Im not sure what is the difference in context I presume between declaring the bean on xml or"@controller

Answer (score 0):

try using @Component on CustomDetail, and use

`<context:component-scan base-package=”your.package” />`

Comment: Hi Subin I updated the code so it will reflect what I have right now I already have those configurations on my XMLs conf files and as you can see I'm also using @service instead of "@"component so I think Spring container will find it. the thing with this code is that it comes from another project so we're trying to reuse it, once again thanks for the help